# Add or remove class on elements with input range

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, slider, range

I have a input range slider. I want to when increased input range, add and remove class on div. My toggleClass not working properly.

```js
function fontRange(e) {
          var element = e.parentElement.id;
          element = ".hello";
          $(element).toggleClass('list' + e.value);
        }
```

```css
* {
color:#fff;
}
.hello {
background:black;
}
.list6 {
background:redç;
}
.list7 {
background:green;
}
.list8 {
background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" value="5" step="1" min="5" max="8" oninput="fontRange(this)" onchange="fontRange(this)">
<div class="hello">
sdfgsdfg
</div>
```

I have a input range slider. I want to when increased input range, add and remove class on div. My toggleClass not working properly.

Comment: `.toggleClass()` turns the class on or off, so if the element already has `list8` in its classlist, moving the slider to 8 will remove it again. Is this what you want? I guess not? Maybe this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ryvL927f/

Comment: Duplicating a not so helpful problem "description" twice doesn't make it better ;) What does _"not working properly"_ mean?

Comment: if the range button is on "6", addclass list6 and remove class others(list7, list8). In the same case if the range button is on "8" addclass list8 and remove class others...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toggleClass` is not the function you need.

Try this:

1. The short way

```js
function fontRange(e) {
    var element = e.parentElement.id;
    element = ".hello";
    $(element).removeClass(); // remove all class, including 'hello'
    $(element).addClass('hello'); // adding class 'hello'
    $(element).addClass('list' + e.value);
}
```

2. The long way:

Removing all the class name start with 'list'

```
function fontRange(e) {
    var element = e.parentElement.id;
    element = ".hello";
    $(element).removeClass (function (index, className) {
       return (className.match(/(^|\s)list\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    });
    $(element).addClass('list' + e.value);
}
```

Comment: the short way will cause a visual problem on change because the background slider will not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You have the main problem with ToggleClass which add or remove one or more class names from selected elements which is not what you need.

Use this to remove all classes except hello.
$("#range").attr('class', 'hello');

Another thing is fontRange() function.

You need only value of input so pass only the value and remove these lines:

```
 var element = e.parentElement.id;
 element = ".hello";
```

```js
function fontRange(value) {
$("#range").attr('class', 'hello').addClass('list' + value);
}
```

```css
* {
    color:#fff;
}
.hello {
    background:black;
}
.list6 {
    background:red;
}
.list7 {
    background:green;
}
.list8 {
    background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" value="5" step="1" min="5" max="8" oninput="fontRange(this)" onchange="fontRange(this.value)">
<div id='range' class="hello">
Range
</div>
```